# How to run DockerOperator on Airflow?

Tags: docker, airflow

I'm setting up a new airflow server using docker-compose and the airflow image puckel/docker-airflow. 
`BashOperators` and `PythonOperator` are working well, but when I'm trying to use `DockerOperator` I'm getting **[/usr/local/airflow/dags/XXXXXXX.py]** No module named 'docker'.

How do I need to change my docker-compose file in order to use docker inside my docker?

I tried to look for the error message on google, but none of the suggested solution worked.

Here is the docker-compose for the `WebServer` I'm using

```
webserver:
    image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.1
    build:
      context: https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow.git#1.10.1
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        AIRFLOW_DEPS: gcp_api,s3,docker        
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - LOAD_EX=n
      - EXECUTOR=Local
      - FERNET_KEY=jsDPRErfv8Z_eVTnGfF8ywd19j4pyqE3NpdUBA_oRTo=
    volumes:
      - ./LOCALPATHTODAGS/dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    command: webserver
```

My end goal is to be able to trigger a docker container of a local image from my airflow pipelines.

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods you could use:

1. Add `before_script` to your current current docker-compose:

```
webserver:
   (...)
   before_script:
   - pip install docker
```

2. Create a `Dockerfile` which uses the one from puckel and install the required package in there.

Answer (score 1):

'docker' is actually also a Python module that is probably imported in the source code of the DockerOperator. Assuming that you install your dependencies in a `requirements.txt` file from within your `Dockerfile`, you could add `docker==4.1.0` into your `requirements.txt` file which should be in the same directory as your `Dockerfile`.

So, in your Dockerfile, you need:

```
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
USER root
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

and in your requirements file, you need:

```
docker==4.1.0  # Other versions probably also work
```

Comment: does this mean that I acctually don't need docker installed inside the container (or, well, installed in the traditional way) ?

Comment: Hi, first, you need docker installed inside the webserver container, so that the DockerOperator of apache airflow can create "sibling" containers which execute the task's source code. You can install docker inside the webserver container by adding `RUN curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh` and `ENV SHARE_DIR /usr/local/share` in the webserver's Dockerfile. Second, you need the Python package `docker==4.1.0` installed in the container executing the task invoked by the DockerOperator. So you need to make sure that in the task's Dockerfile, the package `docker==4.1.0` is installed at some point

Answer (score 0):

Airflow is telling you that you don't have docker installed within airflow's file system. Python and Bash Operators ship by default, but docker is an additional import - similar to many providers e.g aws, gcp.

You'll need to install airflow[docker] in your requirements.txt. And your Dockerfile that spins up the airflow container needs to pip install those requirements. There are some caveats when running dockerOperator within docker-compose i.e. docker in docker but there are other SO threads for that.